# what does the S and K in file name under /etc/init.d/rcx.d stand for

Tags: linux, suse

I'm using Suse11. I know the `/etc/init.d/rcx.d` is used for different run levels. And if you list of the directory, let's say `rc5.d/`.  You can see that the filename either start with **S** or **K**, so what is the meaning behind this naming convention?

Answer (score 4):

Start or Kill to indicate whether that service should or should not run in that runlevel.